# How to alter paths, that are translated by i18n?

Tags: i18n-l10n, uri

I am using language selection by language domain in Drupal 7. That has the side effect, that all internal Drupal paths being created as absolute paths by the i18n module.

To get sub-domains working again I want to alter the paths that are translated by 
i18n. Is there a hook I could use for that?

The function *hook_url_outbound_alter()* is triggered before the path translation by i18n, so it can't be used for that purpose.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you have urls in the form `http://domain.com/subdomain/en/node/23`? Is this what is broken?

If you just want to get rid of the prefix , see [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19078/how-to-redirect-url-with-language-prefix-to-the-same-url-with-no-prefix-default?rq=1)

Comment: I guess what OP meant by subdomain is rather `http://en.domain.com/node/23`