# always include language code in url

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, uri

For SEO reason I need my site to always use language code in the URL. At the moment mysite.com/en/news is also accessible through mysite.com/news, according to my SEO contact, mysite.com/news should return content.

How do I achieve this behavior?

Comment: check this answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19078/how-to-redirect-url-with-language-prefix-to-the-same-url-with-no-prefix-default

Comment: Thanks but that question is about "all the URL **without language prefix** show the Japanese pages". I do not want to use URLs with no language code. I **always** want to use language code. Therefor I having a hard time using the answer for my question.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module with the default options. You can redirects all URLs without a language prefix to the correct URL with the default language prefix contained.

Comment: great minds....

Answer (score 2):

This is what you have (for example):

- mysite.com (default)
- mysite.com/fr (French)

This is what you are looking for (for example):

- mysite.com/en (default)
- mysite.com/fr (French)

This can be accomplished in your language settings. For each language you can set a Path prefix, use en and fr (for my example).

To redirect mysite.com to mysite.com/en you can use the [Global Redirect module](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 you can go to Manage > Configuration > Regional and language > Languages > Detection and selection > URL (configure).
Here you can add a prefix for the URLs for every language.